# Enable Autoplay in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, autoplay

How can I enable the Autoplay prompt in Windows XP?

I have tried the following things:

- right clicking the drive and selecting autoplay and have the radio button for prompt checked.
- I have tried Microsoft's autofix.exe as well. Neither have done the trick. In `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Services/CDROM`, there is an `Autorun - REG_DWORD_0x00000001 (1)`.

Answer (score 3):

read this :

- [Microsoft AutoRun feature or the AutoPlay feature](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/330135)
- [Enabling / disabling Windows AutoPlay](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000130.htm)

or

- Click Start
- Click Run
- Enter GPEDIT.MSC
- Group Policy mmc will popup. On left panel:
- Double-click Computer Configuration to open submenu
- Double-click Administrative Templates to open submenu
- Double-click System to open submenu
- Double-click on Turn off Autoplay
- select Disabled (this will allow autoplay)
- select Apply or Ok

[image: gpedit]

Comment: I have tried both of those sites and the options didn't work

Comment: I have set the autoplay option to disabled in the group policy. Autoplay still does not prompt me when I insert a disc or a flash drive.

Comment: i updated my answer...